# Why DiffUtil Doesn't throw a ClassCastException when using Kotlin Sealed class

Tags: android, kotlin, logging, casting, android-diffutils

I am using sealed class with Android List Adaptor in which 2 different objects are merged into one single list. Last item in the list is just a add more layout(Like Header). I am using DiffUtils and noticed that even i cast newItem to Object1 it doesn't throw any class cast exception.
For example : 1st there are 7 items(6 Object1 + 1 Add More) in Adaptor's currentList then i deleted 1 of the object let that be object with index 6.Now when diffUtil check for areItemsSame() then it doesn't throw an exception. As per my thinking oldItem at 6 will be Object1 since that item is deleted that means now the item at 6 index is Add More and now casting it to Object1 should throw a ClassCastException

My diff util code

```
override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: DataItem, newItem: DataItem): Boolean {
            if (oldItem is DataItem.ItemToDoCat)
            Log.v("Recycler","Old :${(oldItem).toDoCategory.category} ,New ${(newItem as DataItem.ItemToDoCat).toDoCategory.category}")
            return when (oldItem) {

            //Since i am only checking for oldItem, casting newItem should throw an Exception as per my example
                is DataItem.ItemToDoCat -> (oldItem).toDoCategory == (newItem as DataItem.ItemToDoCat).toDoCategory
                is DataItem.ItemAddPlaceHolder -> oldItem == newItem
            }
        }
```

Here is the log before adding test

```
2020-05-28 17:14:42.226 32588-1009/com.example.todomaster V/Recycler: Old :Default ,New Default
2020-05-28 17:14:42.226 32588-1009/com.example.todomaster V/Recycler: Old :Personal ,New Personal
2020-05-28 17:14:42.226 32588-1009/com.example.todomaster V/Recycler: Old :Work ,New Work
```

Log after adding test

```
2020-05-28 17:44:58.643 10717-10779/com.example.todomaster V/Recycler: Old :Default ,New Default
2020-05-28 17:44:58.644 10717-10779/com.example.todomaster V/Recycler: Old :Personal ,New Personal
2020-05-28 17:44:58.644 10717-10779/com.example.todomaster V/Recycler: Old :Work ,New Work
```

Log after deleting test

```
2020-05-28 17:51:33.116 10717-11005/com.example.todomaster V/Recycler: Old :Default ,New Default
2020-05-28 17:51:33.116 10717-11005/com.example.todomaster V/Recycler: Old :Personal ,New Personal
2020-05-28 17:51:33.116 10717-11005/com.example.todomaster V/Recycler: Old :Work ,New Work
```

As you can see Log doesn't even log oldList's test object after deleting which means oldList doesn't had an instance with test Object

Comment: because you have different types in adapter and `newItem` can be `DataItem.ItemAddPlaceHolder` while `oldItem` is `DataItem.ItemToDoCat`?

Comment: You have casted it when logging, compiler is smart enough if any casting fails there, below (when) code is not going to run. So its safe below if it succeed above. If you've used as? instead it will say unchecked cast there (warning)

Comment: But why oldList doesn't have an instance of test Object when i deleted it